# Align all children in same level in vertical using css grid

Tags: css, css-grid

I am designing a form using CSS grid, I got struck with alignment using CSS grid as I am new to CSS grid.

My form field has a label and hints about a field.

I am trying to do align the form field in a row as like below (without javascript).

[image]

But it is not working as expected. Here is the implementation I am trying to do with grid [codepen is here](https://codepen.io/saravananr/pen/RMZWbK)

```css
.wrapper{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(5rem, auto);
  grid-gap: 20px
}

.fieldContainer{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto 1fr;
}

.input{
  height: 35px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.label{
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.hint{
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="fieldContainer">
      <label class="label">Field two bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur</label>
     <div class="input"></div>
    <label for="" class="hint">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo cum quam architecto odit assumenda quo omnis ex ipsam mollitia esse nemo placeat, vitae quae facere dicta, sequi reprehenderit consectetur nobis.</label>
  </div>
  <div class="fieldContainer">
      <label class="label">Field two bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla</label>
     <div class="input"></div>
    <label for="" class="hint">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo cum quam architecto odit assumenda quo omnis ex ipsam mollitia esse nemo placeat.</label>
  </div>
  <div class="fieldContainer">
      <label class="label">Field two bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio eveniet esse quasi perferendis</label>
     <div class="input"></div>
    <label for="" class="hint">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo cum quam </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help or hint where I am making a mistake, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use `grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr auto 1fr);` to `.fieldContainer`. And remove `grid-auto-rows` from `.fieldContainer`.

**Here is the working Snippet:**

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.fieldContainer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr auto 1fr);
}

.input {
  height: 35px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.label {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.hint {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="fieldContainer">
    <label class="label">Field two bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur</label>
    <div class="input"></div>
    <label for="" class="hint">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo cum quam architecto odit assumenda quo omnis ex ipsam mollitia esse nemo placeat, vitae quae facere dicta, sequi reprehenderit consectetur nobis.</label>
  </div>
  <div class="fieldContainer">
    <label class="label">Field two bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla</label>
    <div class="input"></div>
    <label for="" class="hint">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo cum quam architecto odit assumenda quo omnis ex ipsam mollitia esse nemo placeat.</label>
  </div>
  <div class="fieldContainer">
    <label class="label">Field two bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio eveniet esse quasi perferendis</label>
    <div class="input"></div>
    <label for="" class="hint">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo cum quam </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Anzil khaN thanks for answering. I already tried this approach before i posting question here, the problem with this placement is, if field hint text (below the square box)  size is larger than field label (above the square box), then extra white space is coming in the field label. Reason is since we use 1fr for label and hint both share the equal space. Try add more text in hint than label. you can see the difference. I am wondering, Is this alignment problem is possible with css grid?.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need grid-auto rows on the wrapper and just change the fieldContainer to repeat(3, 1fr)

```
.wrapper{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px
}

.fieldContainer{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
}
```

Comment: .fieldContainer{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

Using this will give even space for all child that will result in extra white spaces below and after input box. It will be helpful if you play around on the given posted codepen.